# Java opentelemetry agent enable/disable at run time

Tags: java, dynamic, open-telemetry, otel

what to enable and disable java auto instrumentation done using otel java agent at runtime to avoid redeployment of service in case of issues. Any idea on how we can do this?

we can also do this if we have some way to access and modify tracer used by otel agent.

found nothing on internet

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the agent entirely with [OTEL_JAVAAGENT_ENABLED=false](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/#disabling-the-agent-entirely).

Or you can have the javaagent install instrumentation, but disable the OpenTelemetry SDK with [OTEL_SDK_DISABLED](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure#disabling-opentelemetrysdk).

Or you can suppress specific instrumentation with [OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_[NAME]_ENABLED=false](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/#suppressing-specific-agent-instrumentation).

Comment: But for this we will need redeployment or restart after fetching envs. wanted to do this at run time.

Comment: Yes that's correct. There is currently no way to enable / disable instrumentation at runtime.